# filtering data with .isin() only works for 1 column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, data-analysis

I have a **dictionary** called `df` in which I read a dataset through pandas.

I want to filter out the data such that only rows with values `'S','P'` from the `art_kenzz` column are saved. I tried this:

with this test data https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cykNjViW_DacwWZNaIHWEh3E8OqxsVon/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=115380043465372211112&rtpof=true&sd=true:

```
import pandas as pd

df = {}
df['abc'] = pd.read_excel('./testing.xlsx')
print(df)

df_merged = df['abc'][df['abc']['art_kennz'].isin(['S','P','SP','GP'])]
df_merged.head()
```

However, when I print `df_merged`, it is empty, even though it shouldn't be. But, if I try the same thing with another column:

```
df_merged = df['abc'][df['abc']['zeile'].isin([5])]
```

it works. It would be because all rows in the `zeile` column have a value of 5. So there's nothing to filter out.

Additionally, if I create a dataframe here myself, that also works correctly:

```
dfs = {}
dfs["abc"] = pd.DataFrame({
    "mandant" : [9,9,9,9],
    "fk_eakopf_posnr" : [552025046,552025047,552035009,552035009],
    "zeile" : [5,5,5,5],
    "art_kennz" : ["G","G","G","S"]
})

dfs["abc"][dfs["abc"]['art_kennz'].isin(['S','P'])]
```

However, if I read a dataframe (xlxs file) and put it into the `df`dict (as described in the top code snippet), then it doesn't work. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Well, it looks like the `zeile` column does not contain 5 as you expect, otherwise, as per your 2nd snippet, it would work

Comment: No, I said that that zeile column has all 5s and hence it works. But the same code doesn't work for another column ```art_kennz```. Maybe you can have a look at the dataset to get a better picture @FlorianGD